# How to write test case in mocha

Tags: javascript, tdd, mocha.js

I have this code that i am trying to test using mocha(which i am very new to).

```
function ColorMark(){
    this.color = ""
    var that = this;

    this.create = function(color){
        that.color = color;
        console.log("Created a mark with " + that.color + " color");
    }
}
```

What I have done is this

```
describe('ColorMark', function(){
    describe('#create("red")', function(){
        it('should create red mark',function(){
            assert.equal(this.test.parent.ctx.color, "red");
        })
    })
});
```

Error :

```
AssertionError: "undefined" == "red"
```

`that.color` return `undefined`.

What's wrong with `this` in test context?

Is there something i am missing specifically related to mocha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the code you show, which does not instantiate a `ColorMark` nor actually call `create('red')`, you seem to be thinking that Mocha does more that it actually does. What you put in the first argument of `describe` is primarily for *your* benefit. These are test suite titles. Mocha passes them to the reporters and the reporters display them but that's it.

Here's how you can do it:

```
var assert = require("assert");

function ColorMark(){
    this.color = "";
    var that = this;

    this.create = function(color){
        that.color = color;
        console.log("Created a mark with " + that.color + " color");
    };
}

describe('ColorMark', function(){
    describe('#create("red")', function(){
        it('should create red mark',function(){
            var cm = new ColorMark();
            cm.create("red");
            assert.equal(cm.color, "red");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a small query, I have required in test file.

`var ColorMark = require('../lib/color_mark.js');`

results in `TypeError: object is not a function` at `var cm = new ColorMark()`. I understand the error, but don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You did not export it properly. If you want your module to have for value the `ColorMark` function, you should add the following inside your module: `module.exports = ColorMark`.

Comment: Yeah I should have figured that out. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a beforeEach() clause to set up the test and execute your ColorMark() function.

From the docs:
http://mochajs.org/

```
  beforeEach(function(done){
    db.clear(function(err){
      if (err) return done(err);
      db.save([tobi, loki, jane], done);
    });
  })
```

So in this case it might look like

```
function ColorMark(color){
    this.color = ""
    var that = this;

    this.create = function(color){
        that.color = color;
        console.log("Created a mark with " + that.color + " color");
    }
}

beforeEach(function(){
    ColorMark("red");
});

describe('#create("red")', function(){
    it('should create red mark',function(){
        assert.equal(this.test.parent.ctx.color, "red");
    })
})
```